# Rest of the code is working fine even it is running but in my class i got this error.

Tags: asp.net

```
    public static SqlParameter AddParameter(string parameterName,object value,SqlDbType DbType,int size)
    {

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = parameterName;
        param.Value = value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
        param.SqlDbType = DbType;
        param.Size = size;
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        return param;
    }

    public static DataTable ExecuteDTByProcedure(string ProcedureName ,SqlParameter[] Params)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = ProcedureName;
         cmd.Parameters.AddRange(Params);


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        try
        {

            sda.Fill(dtable);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            sda.Dispose();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();

        }


        return dtable;

    }




}
```

}

> Error:Line 43:             cmd.Connection = con;
>   Line 44:             cmd.CommandText = ProcedureName;
>   Line 45:              cmd.Parameters.AddRange(Params);
>   Line 46: 
>   Line 47:

The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects.
Parameter name: value

Comment: Well the error is telling you exactly what is wrong... You are obviously not supplying valid instances of parameters... did you even try to debug it?

Comment: You're still not showing example code how to use `SqlParameter` array (it is possible that one or more parameters contains null objects). There's seems nothing wrong with `AddParameter` method content, but how you're using it may be throwing error.

Comment: I found the solution, in my other class i was using addproducts() function as

Answer (score 0):

> I found the Solution. In array of SqlParameters, i was inserting with the same index number , where as it must be having indexes starting from 0

SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[4];

```
        parameters[0] =   DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter("@ProductName",ProductName,System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);

        parameters[0] = DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter("@ProductDescription", ProductDescription, System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000);

        parameters[0] =   DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter("@ProductPrice",ProductPrice,System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 100);

        parameters[0] =   DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter("@ProductImage",ProductImage,System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,500);


               DataTable dt = DataLayer.DataAccess.ExecuteDTByProcedure("Sp_AddNewProduct", parameters);
```

> Here is the correct code:

SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[4];

```
        parameters[0] =   DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter("@ProductName",ProductName,System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);

        parameters[1] = DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter("@ProductDescription", ProductDescription, System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000);

        parameters[2] =   DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter("@ProductPrice",ProductPrice,System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 100);

        parameters[3] =   DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter("@ProductImage",ProductImage,System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,500);


               DataTable dt = DataLayer.DataAccess.ExecuteDTByProcedure("Sp_AddNewProduct", parameters);
```

> Note all index numbers are not zero in "Parameters[]"